# Is there anyway to connect Node.js with JBOSS 6.2 using STOMP protocol?

Tags: node.js, stomp, jboss6.x

I would like to know if it is possible to connect Node.js (using stompjs via npm) with JBoss EAP 6.2 using the STOMP protocol. I'm trying and I don't see how to do it.

This is my code:

```
console.log('STOMP: Attempting connection');
stompClient = stomp.overWS(127.0.0.1:4447);
stompClient.connect(
    serviceStompConfig.login,
    serviceStompConfig.passcode,
    _stompSuccessCallback,
    _stompFailureCallback
);
```

I do not receive any errors. In the console I see the message "STOMP: Attempting connection" and that's it. The callback error function is not even executed.

Comment: Please specify, what node STOMP tooling\libraries are you using? What did you try for this moment? Some source code or error messages will make the question much clearer.

Comment: Are you talking about JBoss AS 6.2 or JBoss EAP 6.2?